# How to remove duplicates based on a column from one or more resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, peewee

I have two resultset from the same table in following fashion:

```
|    id    |    name    |    age    |
-------------------------------------
|    1     |    John    |    12     |
|    2     |    Jim     |    23     |
|    3     |    Joel    |    54     |
|    4     |    Jane    |    12     |
```

If i create resultset based on a an age interval and a row occurs as a duplicate between 1 or more resultsets, how can i efficiently filter these based on the `name` column? The amount of resultsets is `1..x`.

Should i: loop through the sets, combine the sets and filter at the same time or can i make a query directly with SQL and remove duplicates?

Since i use `peewee` my queries are eg.:

```
result_1 = Users.select().where(Users.age > 10)
result_2 = Users.select().where(Users.age > 20)
```

**UPDATE:**

There are no duplicates in the actual table, only accross the resultsets, i wish to have either make one resultset without the duplicates, or combine them all without duplicates.

Comment: How do you create your resultset? Show the query.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, i use peewee, but what it generates is very simple queries as we know them. Its very likely that i need to do this particular task in rawquery rather than peewee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) does, out of the box:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Age
FROM Users
WHERE Age > 10

UNION

SELECT ID, Name, Age
FROM Users
WHERE Age > 20;
```

You can do this multiple selects. The requirement is that the selects must all return the same number of columns, with compatible types.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab83f1/2)

**Edit** :
If you need to additionally filter, wrap the union in a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, Name, Age
  FROM Users
  WHERE Age > 10

  UNION

  SELECT ID, Name, Age
  FROM Users
  WHERE Age > 20
) X
WHERE x.Name LIKE 'Jo%';
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab83f1/4)

Comment: This is as close i got myself, but if i only want to use the `Name` column to filter from rather than the `ID` and `Age`? In other words there can only be one `Jane` in that age interval, even though theres more in the table.

Comment: Updated - AFAIK the derived table isn't as performant as a view, however, as the unioned selects will be [materialized](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/31/derived-tables-and-views-performance/) before applying the outer filter, unlike a view. Oracle and SqlServer have CTE's which address this disconnect between views and derived tables.

Comment: Im not quite sure if this solves it entirely. Based on the results from the inner union, how do i filter out all the `name` duplicates so there is only one occurence of lets say `Jane`, this apply to all other `name`s. As i see now the WHERE clause on the additional filter is just hardcoded.

Comment: In other words, i want the union to occur based on `name` and not `age` or `id`.

Comment: In other words, i want to `UNION` based on `name`, this should solve the problem, but then my resultset will just consist of `name`.

Answer (score 1):

you can Try this : (CLM is the duplicated column)

```
delete from Table 
where ID in 
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE WHERE CLM IN (SELECT CLM FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY CLM
HAVING COUNT(*)>1) 
)
```

Comment: Please check my question again, specially the `UPDATE` area.